# Javascript .getHours() returns strange result

Tags: php, javascript, timestamp

I'm converting a PHP timestamp into a human readable form in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var timeleft = new Date( <?php echo $lefttime; ?> * 1000 );

    var hours = timeleft.getHours();
    var minutes = timeleft.getMinutes();
    var seconds = timeleft.getSeconds();

    var countdown = function() {

    console.log( "You have " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " seconds left" );

</script>
```

The minutes and seconds work but I'm getting strange results for the hours. For example:

Timestamp: 1976

Function returns: 19:32:56

Any ideas why I'm getting "19" from `.getHours()` ?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how Date object works. It takes ms since epoch, you are passing 1976. You don't need to use Date at all. The date object does not represent durations.

Comment: @SLaks Well, zero. 1976 seconds equals 32m,56s and the 19 hours is apparently coming out of nowhere. I've already answered why it happens though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that you're in Eastern Time. What you are seeing is `$lefttime` seconds after the epoch, which in the case of EST is 7PM.

[image: XKCD]

To fix it, just use basic math:

```
var timeleft = <?php echo $lefttime; ?>;
var hours = Math.floor(timeleft/3600);
var minutes = Math.floor(timeleft/60)%60;
var seconds = timeleft%60;
```